# Codeigniter - Set a variable in in view

Tags: codeigniter

Can I set a variable in view file?

for exemple:
I have a controller: welcome.php
Its load:

```
$this->load->view('header');
$this->load->view('main');
$this->load->view('footer');
```

I need set a variable on file main.php and get on footer.php

Its possible?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to set a variable in the view for use later on? Because, of course, you can set variables in HTML using standard PHP: `<?php $some_variable = 'Some value'; ?>`.

Answer (score 6):

You can pass a variable from one view to another just like you would from a controller to a view. You just have to load the view file that sets that variable before the view that uses that variable:

```
$this->load->view('main'); //load before
$this->load->view('footer'); //load after
```

Inside of main.php do `$this->load->vars(array('your_variable'=>'it's value'));` and you will be able to call it in the footer like you would any other variable. The only requirement is that main.php be loaded before footer.php.

Comment: It's not good practice to be setting variables inside of views. If you are going to use this method, it's better to call `$this->load->vars()` from the controller rather than from the view, that way you don't need to worry about the order in which you are loading the views.

Comment: @birderic absolutely. I only do this in an extremity of cases. The question isn't about best practices though, but how to load variables from a view.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to set a variable in a view file and access it from another.  There is no reason you should be setting variables in your view files anyway.  The controller should be handling all of your application logic so you should be setting the variable there.  I would recommend reading through the user guide or looking at some articles to get a better grasp of MVC principles.

To access the same variable in multiple views, pass it to each view you load.

```
// Set your variable
$data['variable'] = 'value';

// Pass variable to multiple views
$this->load->view('main', $data);
$this->load->view('footer', $data);
```

Comment: You CAN set a variable in one view and use it in another in codeigniter. I do it all the time. I posted my answer below.

Comment: It's not always about model-related variables, birderic. For instance I use this to set the names of some javascripts inside the "content" view, and then load these files in the footer view, after all the HTML content.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass both **array** or **object** to your view, for example:

```
$data = new StdClass;
$data->title = "The Title";
$data->content = "The Content";

$this->load->view('main', $data);
```

or

```
$data = new SomeClass;
$this->load->view('main', $data);
```

Also, in each view you are able to pass a different data:

```
$data1 = array("key" => "val");
$data2 = $this->some_class->some_method($params);
$data3 = $this->another_class->another_method($params);

$this->load->view('navigation', $data1);
$this->load->view('main', $data2);
$this->load->view('footer', $data3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, to pass variable from controller you can type the variable data after the name of view, this is the example :

```
$data["vehicle"] = $vehicle;
$this->load->view('header',$data);
```

then in your view just call the name of variable :

```
<td>
   <?php echo $vehicle ?>
</td>
```

Hope it can help